# property scope in TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a TabBarController with Tabs A and B. I have an NSMutableArray property defined in Tab B as below:

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *cart;
```

I am updating this property in the .m file of the same tab(Tab B).

Now, my question is: When I hit the back button on either of these tabs and move to the previous view, does this property go out of scope and the values in the property get reset/the property gets assigned to nil? If That is the case is there any way to preserve the property and prevent it form getting assigned to nil when navigated to to the previous view via the back button?

Appreciate your inputs and thoughts.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: What Do you mean by .h and .m file of tab B. tab dont have class file. view or navigation controller associated with them have class file or your tabbarcontroller have class file. and where u go when u press back button?

Comment: The view on the top will be dismissed and released in memory. You need to do something (e.g. write your data to `NSUserDefaults`) to save its data  at `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`.

Comment: @CRDave - This is my structure:

<TableViewController X> -> Tab Bar Controller -> Tab A, Tab B

Tab A -> UIViewController
Tab B-> Navigation Controller -> TableViewController

It is in the above tableviewcontroller(in Tab B) that I am having my NSMutabkeArray property. I set this NSMutableArray via a NSNotification from the UIViewController in Tab A. So when I mean the back btn its the back button on Tab A/Tab B which takes me to previous view in chain-TableViewCtlrr X. So when this back btn is pressed, does my NSMutable array property gets set to nil?If yes, how do i prevent tis. Pls advice.